# How to use webmock with an address that has a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stub, webmock

I am using the webmock gem to stub requests for rspec tests.

One of my requests makes a request to a microservice that includes a type and a timestamp in the address:

```
e.g. www.microservice.com/type=1?timestamp=1521493200
```

I can stub the type easily, but I cannot stub the timestamp because it constantly changes based on the code. How can I stub this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression e.g. `stub_request(:get, /www.microservice.com\/type=1\?timestamp=\d+/)`